# Variable Not in Scope from Tuple

Tags: haskell

I have a function that looks like the following:

```
format input = 
   let
      input (name,_,_,_) = name
      n = 15 - length name
```

The purpose of this is to get a value from a tuple and store that value (the name) into a variable called name. Then I make a new variable called n which subtracts the length of that string from a number. When I compile this, I get an error saying that "name" is out of scope on the n = ... line.

> Variable not in scope: name :: t1 a2

Not exactly sure where to go from here or what I might need to change.

Comment: What value do you expect `name` to have on the RHS of `input (name,_,_,_) = name`?

Comment: @chepner My tuple is setup as "type input = (String,Double,Int,Int)", so name would be a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `input` goes on the right-hand side; the pattern `(name, _, _, _)` by itself goes on the left.

```
format input = 
    let (name, _, _, _) = input
        n = 15 - length name
    in ...
```